# Is it possible to have authoryear-style citations with the IEEEtran document class?

Tags: natbib, ieeetran

For school I have to write a paper and use the IEEEtran bibliography style:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
% argument is your BibTeX string definitions and bibliography database(s)
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,bibliography.bib}
```

Now I want to include the natbib package so I can cite my papers in the following way:

> Cook et. al. [1]

The entry for that cite in my bib file is as follows:

```
@ARTICLE{cook2009ambient,
  author = {Cook, D.J. and Augusto, J.C. and Jakkula, V.R.},
  title = {Ambient intelligence: Technologies, applications, and opportunities},
  journal = {Pervasive and Mobile Computing},
  year = {2009},
  volume = {5},
  pages = {277--298},
  number = {4}
}
```

Now if I include the natbib package it complains: "natbib bibliography not compatible with author-year citations" So I load it with option numbers but then my authors are not shown in the latex file.

So how can I cite in the explained way? Without changing anything of the bibliographystyle option. Thanks!

EDIT: I included the template we start with from school:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc,twoside,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
    \usepackage{algorithmic}
    \usepackage[tight,normalsize,sf,SF]{subfigure}
    \usepackage{url}


    \hyphenation{}

    \begin{document}
    \title{Butler Robot Localization Using Dash7 Technology}

    \author
    {

            \thanks
            {

            }
    }

    \IEEEcompsoctitleabstractindextext{%
    \begin{abstract}

    \end{abstract}

    \begin{IEEEkeywords}

    \end{IEEEkeywords}}

    % make the title area
    \maketitle
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \IEEEdisplaynotcompsoctitleabstractindextext
    \section{Example}
    Example!

    % references section

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
% argument is your BibTeX string definitions and bibliography database(s)
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,bibliography.bib}

\vfill

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your proposed citation style, viz., `Cook et al. [1]`, would appear to be an unusual hybrid of *author-year* and *numeric* citation styles. Are you sure you don't want to see the citation appear as `Cook et al. (2009)`, say? Please post a complete MWE (minimum working example), as your code snippets do not seem to permit a deep analysis of what's going on. E.g., I have a feeling that you're loading a document class that either already loads the `natbib` package or already sets up a numeric citation style.

Comment: Added extra snipped as you asked :)

Comment: Thanks for providing the extra code. The IEEEtran document class indeed expects a numeric citation style, and the `cite` package that's loaded by default provides some useful features when dealing with numeric citations. Unless you can convince your school to let you use an entirely different document class, I'm afraid there's probably no point in you trying to introduce an authoryear-style citation method for your document(s).

Comment: @Mico I asked if its possible, another option would be to type it myself but thats against the idea of using LaTex. Is there any macro/custom command that I could use to achieve my goal?

Comment: Short of doctoring some of the setup provided by the `IEEEtran.cls` document class file and the `ieeetran.bst` bibliography style file, I'm afraid you're not going to get authoryear-style citations in your document. :-(  Incidentally, since you're using the `compsoc` document option, the `cite` package should be loaded with the `nocompress` option, i.e., as `\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}`. See p. 7 of the user guide to the `IEEEtran` document class, which notes that "One complication in compsoc mode is that the Computer Society does not compress, but does sort, adjacent citation numbers."

Comment: IEEE accepts the usage of numbers as *In [3], they did this and that* hence the reason.

Comment: @Mico thanks for your time, I think my school needs to decide what they want (use IEEE standards or implement their own).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the following output:

```
Cook et. al. [1]
```

First you include the natbib package as follows:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

Then download the IEEEtranN bibliography style (a simple [google](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtranN.bst)) and then put it in the same location as your latex file. Now change the following lines as follows:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,bibliography}
```

You can now use `citet` and other natbib varians, the numbering will stay in the order it first appeared (and not the order of your bib file) and the reference layout is the same as with the IEEEtran bibliography style.

Comment: I am getting this error message: `** Natbib version - not for normal IEEE work.`

Comment: the problem with this solution is that it overrides the original `cite` command, which leads to citations of the form [1,2,3] instead of [1], [2], [3], which is required for IEEE Computer Society. Any further thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Add following line after document class in your main tex file

```
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
```