# Author not showing with IEEEtran and natbib

Tags: bibtex, citing, ieeetran

I am using a template for a conference. See file icmcsmc2014.sty.

They define IEEEtran as bibtex environment. Now I really want to display the name of the author on some citations. Normally I would use \citet, however IEEEtran does not allow this. Based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102775/is-it-possible-to-have-authoryear-style-citations-with-the-ieeetran-document-cla) I tried adding

```
     \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

Now citet is recognised, but it displays "author?". I think it is a clash with the stylesheet of so.

[image]

Any ideas?

A second issue I am having is that the title of the references is not displayed, but printed in small below the empty title with the number.

Here is a [minimal working example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/test.tex) and the [sty file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/icmcsmc2014.sty) that comes alongs with it. Sorry I didn't see an upload button and was unsure on how to attach the sty file. I will also put the min working example here:

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{icmcsmc2014}

 \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}



\begin{filecontents}{paper_test.bib}
@article{herremans2013composing,
  title={Composing Fifth Species Counterpoint Music With A Variable Neighborhood Search Algorithm},
  author={Herremans, Dorien and S{\"o}rensen, Kenneth},
  journal={Expert Systems with Applications},
  volume={40},
  number={16},
  pages={6427--6437},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Pergamon}
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% \usepackage{cite}
%   \usepackage{multibib}



% ***************************************** the document starts here ***************
\begin{document}



\section{Introduction}

Here I want the author name to occur with citet as it is said by \citet{herremans2013composing}.

%   \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
%   \bibliographystyle{natbib}
  \bibliography{paper_test}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the interested reader, loading natbib before the template already solves my section title problem.

Also commenting out \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} in the template solves it. Though I am a bit concerned about the journal using the original .sty file.