# Author name not showing when using IEEEtran bib style

Tags: bibtex, citing, ieeetran

If I use the IEEEtran bibstyle with the default Bibtex

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

the bib entry below gets listed in the references section without author name.

```
@Article{simon_comments_1952,
  Title                    = {Comments on the Theory of Organizations},
  Author                   = {Simon, Herbert A},
  Journal                  = {The American Political Science Review},
  Year                     = {1952},
  Number                   = {4},
  Pages                    = {pp. 1130-1139},
  Volume                   = {46},
  ISSN                     = {00030554},
  Publisher                = {American Political Science Association}
}
```

where this one shows just fine:

```
@Article{simon_architecture_1962,
  Title                    = {The architecture of complexity},
  Author                   = {Simon, Herbert A},
  Journal                  = {Proceedings of the American philosophical society},
  Year                     = {1962},
  Number                   = {6},
  Pages                    = {467--482},
  Volume                   = {106},
  Category                 = {hierarchy},
  Doi                      = {10.2307/985254},
}
```

Here is a screenshot

[image: references without name]

Any idea why? They look exactly the same in terms of syntax. If I am not missing something, it looks kind of random to me.

Ps, the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161158/author-not-showing-with-ieeetran-and-natbib) is not applicable (I could not find the style file being referenced).

Comment: The `IEEEtran` bibliography style is programmed to replace repeated author names with two consecutive em-dashes. This is a very common bibliographic formatting convention.

Comment: oh! so it is not in the other because it is already listed above it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the query has been answered in one of the comments.