# How to produce citations like [1], [2] instead of [1,2] using natbib?

Tags: citing, natbib, ieeetran

There are plenty of questions asking for the other way around (which are usually answered by "use natbib"). I use natbib for a different reason: I use IEEEtran and [need `\citet`-style referencing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103025/81836), so I load natbib like `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`.

However, if I use `\cite{ref1, ref2}`, I get references like [1,2], but what I need is [1], [2], which I would get if I wouldn't load `natbib`. How can I enforce references in the form of [1], [2] using natbib?

Comment: Using `\setcitestyle{citesep={], [}}` I can produce a hacky "[1], [ 2]"-style citing, but how to get rid of the extra whitespace?

Comment: The `IEEEtran` styles are designed to be used with the `cite` package not `natbib`.

Comment: @AlanMunn No, this is exactly the opposite case I mentioned in the first sentence. I *do* get citations like [1,2,3], but *what I want* is [1], [2], [3]

Comment: @AlanMunn I know, but the "cite" package has no `\citet` right?

Comment: True, the answer undoes what you want, but what you want is what the OP in that question is getting with the `cite` package, which is what you need to use for `IEEEtran`. The `citet` vs. `citep` distinction only makes sense with author/year styles.  So just use `\cite`.

Comment: @AlanMunn But how can I print the name of the authors without using natbib? Is there some minimal package I get load aside of `cite` which allows printing author names? What I essentially want is printing something like "Skywalker et al. [2] proposed XXX"

Comment: You ask, "How can I enforce references in the form of `[1], [2]` using natbib?" Is somebody or something keeping you from writing `\citet{ref1}, \citet{ref2}`?

Comment: You also wrote, "What I essentially want is printing something like `Skywalker et al. [2] proposed XXX'." Are you looking for the [vancouver](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/vancouver) bibliography style.

Comment: Along the lines of the separator workaround you can use `\setcitestyle{citesep={], [\kern-.2222em}}`, so put some negative space before the next number.

Comment: @Mico Yes, the automatic ordering by appearance which is done by natbib keeps me from writing `\citet{ref1}, \citet{ref2}`

Comment: @Mico I obviously didn't sufficiently point out, that "Skywalker et al. [2] proposed" is a special case, but the regular case is citing like "[1], [2]"